# Browsers: console groups

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, console

I have this code:

```
console.log('before');

console.groupCollapsed('main');
console.log('test1')
console.groupEnd();

console.groupCollapsed('main');
console.log('test2')
console.groupEnd();

console.groupCollapsed('main');
console.log('test2')
console.groupEnd();

console.log('after');
```

It adds 3 lines to browser logs.
The problem is logs are splitted into 3 different groups.
Is it possible to append logs to previous group if previous log message and the current one have same group names (`main`)?

So now output is:

```
before
> main
    test1
> main
    test2
> main
    test3
after
```

and I want this output:

```
before
> main
    test1
    test2
    test3
after
```

**Update**: Code is async. So I should close the groups after logging to prevent logging from outside the groups to groups.

Comment: What about the obvious act of not using `groupEnd` before using console.log? Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reopen a new group unless you really want to create a new group. So once you open a group, whatever you *log* will be attached to that group until you close it.

So with your example it would be

```
console.log('before');

console.groupCollapsed('main');
console.log('test1');
console.log('test2');
console.log('test2');
console.groupEnd();

console.log('after');
```

It shouldn't bother you but it takes a bit of a time for the browser to log these in groups. Just an additional note.

Comment: The problem it's impossible in asynchronous code. I may have a wrapper, that will open/close groups, but I will have a problem with code, that uses plain console.log without this wrapper.

Comment: In that case my suggestion would be to keep these within arrays until you're okay to log. Because if you happen to close a group there's no way to sneak back into that old group (because it will have already been output in console).

Comment: The problem is the code is async, and I should log straightway to see the code flow.

Comment: I get that. But as I mentioned, once you close a group or open a new one there's no way you can get back to the old one unless the one you're targeting has already been done with outputting. However, if it is not closed yet you still have that chance. Just keep the desired group open, track the name of the current open group somewhere (ideally, the whole tree in an object reference) and check if it is the desired one and close if it is an inner group when necessary. Let me know if I confused you in any way.

Comment: If there is a log message between messages in groups, that's ok that it interrupts the group and the new group will be started. If I will track groups manually, I will have problems with code, that didn't track groups (other libraries).

Comment: I'm just telling you how grouping in the console works. It's up to you to tailor your needs or find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 4):

How about a custom logger class

```
function Logger(){
    var logs = [];
    var gname = "default";
    function group(name){
        gname = name
    }
    function log(){
        !!logs[gname] || (logs[gname] = []);
        logs[gname].push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
    }
    function flush(){
      console.log(logs) // loop for groups or just output array
      logs=[]; // clear values
    }
    return {group:group,flush:flush,log:log}
}
```

Usage

```
var l = new Logger()
l.group('main1');
l.log('foo','bar','foobar')
l.log('foo-bar')

l.group('main2');
l.log('foo')
l.log('bar')

l.group('main1');
l.log('foo2bar')
l.log('bar2foo')

l.group('main3');
l.log('foo')
l.log('bar')

l.group('main1');
l.log('foo3')
l.log('bar3')

l.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

You only can do that by not closing the group. You could use something like this:

```
var curGroup;
console.logInGroup = function(group, log) {
    if (curGroup != group) {
        console.groupEnd();
        console.groupCollapsed(curGroup = group);
    }
    console.log.apply(console, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
};

console.log('before');
console.logInGroup('main', 'test1');
console.logInGroup('main', 'test2');
console.logInGroup('main', 'test2');
console.groupEnd();
console.log('after');
```

Comment: That will not work: `console.log('middle')` after `console.logInGroup('main', 'test2');` will log in `main` group.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to log outside of the group you will need to end it manually. If fear you don't get around tracking the currently open groups when you transparently want to hide open/close commands.